# Display Text when button is click on MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm totally new to c++, MFC. 
Currently trying out on doing a GUI with a button
and to display a "hello world" text when the button is pressed.
How i can do it?

THANKS

Comment: If you're okay with the text being displayed in a new window, it's really easy: just use [the `MessageBox` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505.aspx). MFC might have a special way to do this, but the raw Windows API function for that is pretty easy, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on MFC:

- http://courses.washington.edu/css450/2008.Fall/web_contents/from_students/450Hints/mfc_tutorial/index.html

Basically, you need to:

1) Create a button and an edit field or label (resource editor)

2) Define an "OnClick" event handler (class editor)

3) "SetWindowText()" on the label in your event handler

This link shows examples for steps 2 and 3:

- http://www.gidforums.com/t-3645.html

Comment: I couldn't find any label nor resource editor. i only can find static text. the software i'm using is Microsoft visual studio MFC.

Comment: The resource editor is available from "View, Resource View" or [Resources] in your project pane.  Event Handlers can be created with <right-click>, Add Event Handler.  The tutorial I cited discusses both of these - and much more.